# What is the text on the loading screens in Gray Matter?

Tags: gray-matter

I've just started playing Jane Jensen's *Gray Matter*. The load screens between scenes contain interesting tidbits about Oxford, magic and Samantha, but they go by too fast. I can't find an option for slowing them down. Is there something I'm missing, a workaround, or a web page listing them?

Comment: If you're playing on Windows, you can capture screenshots and catalogue all of them!